# Using salinity to predict rainfall

Tags: meteorology, oceanography, weather-forecasting, rainfall, salinity

Recently, [a new method](https://www.whoi.edu/oceanus/feature/a-rainfall-forecast-worth-its-salt/) has been proposed by [Ray Schmitt (WHOI)](https://directory.whoi.edu/profile/rschmitt/) and collaborators to use salinity patterns in the ocean to predict weather events (more specifically, rainfall) at scales from weeks to months. First, [they were able to predict](https://dx.doi.org/10.1126/sciadv.1501588) rainfall in the Sahara region. More recently, they have expanded their methodology to predict weather in the US and their method performed better than most of the traditional approaches (that included patterns like El Niño).

Predictions for  Apr 23 – May 6, 2019 (Source: [Salient Predictions](https://salientpredictions.launchrock.com/))
[image: Predictions for Apr 23 – May 6, 2019]
Considering that we are having more and better salinity information from satellites ([SMOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soil_Moisture_and_Ocean_Salinity) and [SMAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soil_Moisture_Active_Passive)):

- can we expect to have a better global seasonal rainfall prediction in the near future [as they described](https://salientpredictions.launchrock.com/)?
- What are the limitations of the approach?
- How far in the future can we extend the approach?

Comment: Interesting approach. Any Indian monsoon predictions with this approach ? I would be really fascinated by that.

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: yes thanks. I contacted them. They said they will get back. Maybe we can test a potential forecast for this summer if they give me data that is not available to the public.

Comment: is one of the authors somebody you know ?

Comment: Maybe. Our community is rather small :-)

Comment: I agree it is small. Maybe you know me and I know you but the world does not :-)

Comment: They contacted me !!!

Comment: @gansub, they are great group of people and amazing scientists.

Comment: I replied back. They are going to be starting their own company soon and I am hoping they are going to give me a free preview. First one from my country etc and their stuff also new etc.

Comment: They got back to me saying no funds for Indian subcontinent. Is there a website that shows salinity of my basin in real time ? Or we can assume whereever there is warm pool it is low salinity and cold pool is excess salinity?

Comment: @gansub, check SMOS data

Comment: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10236-013-0660-y https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6266690 https://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/full/10.1175/JCLI-D-14-00435.1